# Why is there an odd error message when using the min() function?

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, min

When I execute the following code, for some reason I get an odd error message.

I've tried changing int to float, but nothing worked.

```
number = float(input("Please enter an integer number."))
if number % 1 == 0:
    list = []
    list.append(number)
    add = input("Would you like to add any more integers? Type Y for yes and N for no.")
    while add == "Y":
        newnumber = input("What is the next integer?")
        list.append([newnumber])
        add = input("Would you like to add any more integers? Type Y for yes and N for no.")
    if add == "N":
        print("Length: %s" % len(list))
        print("Minimum: %s" % int(min(list)))
else:
    print("This is not an integer. Please restart.")
```

This happened during line 12, or the print("Minimum ...) line.
'<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
is the error message.
I don't think I ever put the character < in line 12.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please change list.append([newnumber]) to list.append(int(newnumber)) because you are appending a list([8.0, ['9'], ['6']]) instead of another integer in the list

```
number = float(input("Please enter an integer number."))
if number % 1 == 0:
    list = []
    list.append(number)
    add = input("Would you like to add any more integers? Type Y for yes and N for no.")
    while add == "Y":
        newnumber = input("What is the next integer?")
        list.append(int(newnumber))
        add = input("Would you like to add any more integers? Type Y for yes and N for no.")
    if add == "N":
        print("Length: %s" % len(list))
        print("Minimum: %s" % int(min(list)))
else:
    print("This is not an integer. Please restart.")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.